# Proof of Theorem in Measure Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-measure

I am looking for a proof/reference of the following theorem in measure theory:

> Every isometry-invariant Radon measure $\mu$ on $[\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}^d]$ is a constant multiple of the Lebesgue measure, means $\mu = c \lambda$ for a constant $c\geq 0$.

I found this statement in "Stochastic Geometry and its Application" by Stoyan, Kendall, and Mecke, but there was neither a proof nor a reference.

If you know about a reference, please let me know.

Comment: Try to show that if $\mathrm{R}$ is a rectangle with dimensions $l_i,$ then $\mu(\mathrm{R}) = \mu([0,1]^d) (l_1 \cdots l_d).$ Having this, you get the result on rectangles, hence everywhere since the rectangles generate the Borel sets.

Comment: Okay thank you. I actually need this for my thesis. So i don´t want to proof it by myself (it is not that important). Do you know any reference with the theorem and the proof?

Comment: It's a well-known fact that the only measures that are translation invariant are constant multiples of Lebesgue measure. I would assume this result should appear on every measure theory book.